# Как можно обфусцировать C код через NDK?

Tags: java, android

Как можно обфусцировать Си код через ndk, или как вообще это сделать

Comment: Для машинного кода обфускация имеет мало смысла. Какую проблему вы пытаетесь решить?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev  пытаюсь сделать так чтоб когда реверснули апк и там будут файлы .so что не смогли изменить данные и и не смогли взять оттуда данные тоже ну чтоб не читаемо было

Comment: so - это бинарник, взять из него данные или изменить их чрезвычайно сложно. Способных на это не остановит никакая обфускация. Она может только замедлить процесс, но ценой увеличения размера so-файлов и снижения скорости их работы.

Comment: .so реверснуть также легко как .apk???

Comment: но всеравно хотело сь бы узнать если такое решение для андроида )